# Can I have my app scan my Twitter stream for news to show the user?

Tags: regex, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter

I would like to be able to show short news messages to users of my app.  I am thinking the nicest way to do this would be to add a hashtag (like #appnews) to my Twitter updates that I want shown in-app; my app will make this happen by scanning my Twitter stream at startup and surfacing updates with that hashtag.  This seems super-simple, and I'd like to know if there's some way to do this via built-in (HTTP?) calls to my Twitter page, rather than incorporating a whole framework like MGTwitterEngine.  The user will not be logging in or posting Twitter updates at any point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve any user's public tweets in XML format by retrieving the following URL:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=DWRoelands

(This example will display my tweets).  Once you've got the list of tweets, you can parse through the XML document in whatever way is easiest for you.

Rather than tagging posts with a hash tag, I would recommend simply starting a new Twitter account that is solely for the news items you described.